# I don't know if my solution to a supremum problem is correct

Tags: real-analysis, logic, supremum-and-infimum

I found an interesting problem, but I couldn't find someone who solved it like I did, so I am asking if I've gone wrong somewhere.

Let $S \subseteq R$ be nonempty. Prove that if a number $u$ in $R$ has the properties:

(i) for every $n \in N$ the number $u - \frac{1}{n} $ is not an upper bound of S, and

(ii) for every number $n \in N$ the number  $u + \frac{1}{n}$ In is an upper bound of S,

then u = **sup** S.

Now notice that this is an implication, $(i) \land(ii) \implies u =$ **sup** S. So I used the contrapositive to prove it:

$ u \neq$ **sup** S $ \implies \lnot(i) \lor \lnot(ii)$

This is what I did:

Notice that (i) is the same as saying: for every $n \in N$, there exits an $s \in S$ such that $ u - \frac{1}{n} < s$.

The negation of (i) is : there exits a natural number $n$ such that for all $s \in S$ we have $u-\frac{1}{n} \geq s $.

Simply solve the inequality $u-\frac{1}{n} \geq $ **sup S** for $n$, we get $ n \geq \frac{1}{u-sup S}$.

And since $ u \neq$ **sup** S  the donaminator is not zero. The Archimedian property garantees the existence of this $n$.

As for (ii), the negation is: there exits a natural $n$ and an $s \in S$ such that $  u + \frac{1}{n} \leq s$ .

Since $u$ is not the upper bound, there exists an $s' \in S$ such that $s' >  u$.
So we solve the inequality $  u + \frac{1}{n} \leq s'$ for $n$, we obtain $n \geq \frac{1}{s'-u}$.

By the Archimedean property such $n$ exits.

And I am done with the proof.

Comment: Your proof is not exactly correct as you have written it, but the idea is indeed correct. You must be careful, because you want to prove that $u\not=\sup S$ implies $\lnot(i)\lor\lnot(ii)$, but as your proof is stated it seems that you are using what you want to prove in order to get it. I think you should divide the proof in two parts, $u>\sup S$ and $u<\sup S$. For the first one, take $n \geq \frac{1}{u-\sup S}$, and you get that $\lnot(i)$ is satisfied. For the second, as $u$ is not an upper bound, it does exists your $s'>u$ and taking $n \geq \frac{1}{s'-u}$ to get that $\lnot(ii)$ is true

Comment: @Eparoh I don't really understand, this is an implication, I can use the condition $u \neq supS$ to show the result ~(i) and ~(ii).

Comment: As you have written your proof, it seems that you are using $u \not = \sup S$ and $\lnot(i)$ to prove $\lnot(i)$. See that you state what $\lnot(i)$ says, and after that you state: "Simply solve the inequality $u - \frac{1}{n} \geq \sup S$..." as if you already know that such an $n$ already exists, but you don't. The way you've written it is a good way to scratch things, to see how can you prove it, buy when writting the formal proof, you have to work backwards, because you don't know that there exists an $n$ satisfying $u - \frac{1}{n} \geq \sup S$ unless you already assume $\lnot(i)$ is true

Comment: @Eparoh Ah ok, now I understand. So in the formal proof I should've said: by the archimedean property we have $n \geq \frac{1}{u-sup S}$ (since $u \neq sup S$ the denominator is not 0), and then build up from here to reach $u - \frac{1}{n} \geq supS \geq s$ for all $s \in S$. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But just one detail. You should also distinguish between the two cases $u > \sup S$ and $u < \sup S$, because if $u < \sup S$, then $u - \sup S <0$ and from $n \geq \frac{1}{u-sup S}$ you get $u - \frac{1}{n} \leq \sup S$. So, for every case you should argue as you have done in that comment to get $\lnot(i)$ or $\lnot(ii)$.